# database query filling the var/temp

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel, whm, pligg

I am not a programmer so please be gentle :)

Following query on our website loads a lot of data to server's var/temp folder and creates server load and all sorts of troubles.

```
{php}
global $db;


$res = $db->get_results("select * from ".table_links." , pligg_files where      link_status='queued' and file_link_id = link_id and  file_size = '85x85' ORDER BY   `link_date` DESC LIMIT  5");

echo "<ul class='upcomstory'>";
foreach($res as $rslink)
{

$rslink->link_title = utf8_substr($rslink->link_title, 0, 40) . '...';

$cat = $db->get_var("select category_name from ".table_categories." where category__auto_id='".$rslink->link_category."'");
$catvar = $db->get_var("select category_safe_name from ".table_categories." where category__auto_id='".$rslink->link_category."'");
//echo "<li><div class='stcon'><div class='stpic'><img class='stimg' alt='".$rslink->link_title."' src='".my_base_url.my_pligg_base."/modules/upload/attachments/thumbs/".$rslink->file_name."' /></div><a href='".my_base_url.my_pligg_base."/story.php?id=".$rslink->link_id."'>".$rslink->link_title."</a><br /><br /> <span style='color:#044B9B;font-weight:bold;'>".$rslink->link_votes."</span> Vote -In: <span style='font-weight:bold;color:#044B9B;'>".$cat."</span></div> </li>";
echo '<li><div class="stcon"><div class="stpic"><img class="stimg" alt="'.$rslink->link_title.'" src="'.my_base_url.my_pligg_base.'/modules/upload/attachments/thumbs/'.$rslink->file_name.'" /></div><a href="'.my_base_url.my_pligg_base.'/story.php?id='.$rslink->link_id.'">'.$rslink->link_title.'</a><br /><br /> <span style="color:#044B9B;font-weight:bold;">'.$rslink->link_votes.'</span> Vote(s) </div> </li>';

}

echo "</ul>";
{/php}
```

Is there a way to 'clear' the output automatically as part of this query once every few minutes?

Thanks

Comment: When you say 'lots of data', how big are the files we're talking about? The top query only returns 5 results so I can't imagine something like this causing a heap of data. How many users hit this code?

Comment: Hi, I think this query doesn't cache anything and runs for every user who accesses the website and hence creating the load. There are around 5000 users who access the site everyday.

Comment: You'd be a lot better off looking how to turn on some decent caching or looking at some other optimizations. Have you tried asking over at the Pligg forums ( http://forums.pligg.com/ ) because this definitely looks like a framework specific problem. They may have a fix.

Comment: thanks mate ..this is outside the framework - just a hack to display images on the sidebar. I am sure there is a way to do it within framework but programmer we hired was too lazy to do it the right way.

Comment: Then at least get him to cache it so it doesn't hammer your database. Honestly, if I were you I'd get him to fix the problem - deleting the temp files is a super dodgy workaround that could lead to some wacky stuff happening for users (timeouts, non-returned queries etc). Caching will help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear how this could be filling your directory. But, you could use a cron job to periodically clean out that folder.  This will delete any files that are older than 60 minues.

> @hourly find /var/temp/ -mmin +60 -exec rm {} \;

Comment: @KBS: You should **REALLY** know (and understand) what's going into your `/var/temp/` directory before just deleting things every hour. This could cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: @mwan Agreed. Only reason I suggested such an agressive approach is that I've never seen a standard `/var/temp` and made the assumption that someone put the directory specifically to store temporary files.